# create virtual patient data set

Tags: r, tibble

I would like to create a virtual patient data set in R , where in I would like to have the following time points TIME = seq(1, 10, 1), be repeated for 3 unique patient IDs 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @markus, you can use `expand.grid`:

```
df <- expand.grid(TIME = 1:10, ID = 1:3)
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for `expand.grid(1:10, 1:3)`

Comment: Thanks @markus I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you so much @markus and bjornkallerud

Comment: how about the AMT column though ? how to add the AMT such that it appears only during the first time point for each ID?

Comment: @abc Try `df$AMT <- ifelse(df$TIME == 1, 10L, NA_integer_)`